# Display image in order comment in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have added a comment to order on checkout success page. The comment is path to an image file. I want to display the image there rather than its path.

I added the following code for adding the comment,

```
$order->setState('processing', 'invoiced', $img_path);
```

Is it possible if I send html of image and image is shown rather than path?

Comment: What is the content of '$img_path'? Is it <img src='http ://xyz.com/path/to/img.jpg'> ? Also if you type the image path into your browser does it display the image?

Comment: Yes, i added this $img_path = '<img src="http://imgsource"/>' . But it is being displayed as same. I inspected it with firebug and it comes in a br tag. But it doesn't create an image tag!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom module that extend  app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml

Change Line #71 from

```
        <?php if ($_item->getComment()): ?>
            <br/><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), array('b','br','strong','i','u')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

To

```
        <?php if ($_item->getComment()): ?>
            <br/><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getComment(), array('b','br','strong','i','u', 'img')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

(If you have any issues check the value of 'comment' in sales_flat_order_status_history db to see if it already escapeHtml)

Comment: Done this but still it displays <img src="/magento/casemate/canvas/canvasc27fe50005081cf47eeeafcf687ac93e.png"> and not image!

Comment: Change the middle line to <br/><?php echo $_item->getComment() ?>

Comment: It's alway a good idea to escape html... take a look at escapeHtml() method in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php